# How to download youtube videos in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, youtube

I am looking for free alternatives to download youtube videos in Safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few extensions that will add a nice download button to the Youtube video page, and give you the option to download in various resolutions.

- [Youtube Video Downloader](https://github.com/jonathanboom/YouTube-video-downloader-for-Safari/downloads)
- [Fastesttube](http://kwizzu.com)
- [YouTubeDownloader](http://code.google.com/p/safari-extensions/downloads/detail?name=YouTubeDownloader.safariextz&can=2&q=)

You can also try [ClickToPlugin](http://hoyois.github.com/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/), which does a lot more than just offer a download link, but it does that, and it's one of my favourite extensions. Makes watching web video much nicer.

Comment: Any idea if they work with private videos? I tried all of them but none seems to add any options to the toolbar or the video page.

Answer (score 4):

Although not a safari plugin, a good alternative is the youtube-dl python script which works everywhere.

It can be downloaded on [this github page](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/).

If you want to use this directly from Safari then you could create a Service like this with automator (the path to the python script should be modified accordingly)

[image: Automator script to download selected YouTube URL]

With this service you can select a URL in Safari (for example in the address bar) and access it from the right click menu or the Services menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Save Tube](http://www.savetube.com/).

It is Java based and it is safe (see [here for more deatails](http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/savetube.com))