# Downloading YouTube music videos

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, video, youtube

Is there a reliable YouTube video converter than can download music videos?

I am a professor teaching overseas and often download music videos for classroom use. For example, gospel songs and Christmas songs for my Intro to the Bible course.

ClipConverter use to download both talking and musical vids, but now blocks musical videos.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.   Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Comment: Let’s assume this is macos requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download youtube videos in Safari?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69012/how-to-download-youtube-videos-in-safari)

Comment: I don't know if it gets around these restrictions, but there are applications simply for downloading youtube videos, such as [Airy](https://mac.eltima.com/youtube-downloader-mac.html) or [4K Video Downloader](https://www.4kdownload.com/products/product-videodownloader).

Comment: Let's leave this open - it's clearly getting some command-line options and isn't tied to any one browser like Safari or Chrome. The link to the other question is excellent to keep, though @slhck

Comment: I am creating a website to download video with out any advertisements or non sense you get with other ones. I post the code here once I have finished if you would like.  It will use `youtube-dl` from Nimesh Neema's answer.

Comment: I have posted the code. Check my answer.

Answer (score 12):

If you use command-line (**Terminal.app** in macOS) or even if you have a passing familiarity with it, using [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) is recommended.

`yt-dlp` is available for macOS, Windows as well as Linux. The usage is very simple, just type the following command-line in Terminal (I have used an example video for demonstration purposes. Replace the URL with the appropriate one as desired):

`yt-dlp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw`

That's it. It will download the video in the best available quality. There are no ads or any questionable content involved. Also there is no risk of downloading any inadvertent software/malware. **yt-dlp** downloads videos at best available speed for your Internet connection (unlike many other tools). It also supports download resuming (helpful if the connection breaks midway).

`yt-dlp` is not a built-in command in macOS. The easiest and best way to install it would be via using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). Follow the instructions on the linked webpage to install Homebrew. Once installed, run the following command to install `yt-dlp`:

`brew install yt-dlp`

Using `yt-dlp`, you can also download the video in lower resolution (for e.g. to watch on mobile device or to share over a messenger) or just the **audio only** or **video only** stream from the video.

To select the download quality or type, simply, execute the command with an additional `-F` option to list all the available formats for a YouTube video as:

`yt-dlp -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw`

The output will show all the available formats as:

```
[youtube] Extracting URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw
[youtube] jNQXAC9IVRw: Downloading webpage
[youtube] jNQXAC9IVRw: Downloading ios player API JSON
[youtube] jNQXAC9IVRw: Downloading android player API JSON
[youtube] jNQXAC9IVRw: Downloading m3u8 information
[info] Available formats for jNQXAC9IVRw:
ID  EXT  RESOLUTION FPS CH │   FILESIZE  TBR PROTO │ VCODEC         VBR ACODEC      ABR ASR MORE INFO
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
233 mp4  audio only        │                 m3u8  │ audio only         unknown             Default
234 mp4  audio only        │                 m3u8  │ audio only         unknown             Default
599 m4a  audio only      2 │   72.95KiB  31k https │ audio only         mp4a.40.5   31k 22k ultralow, m4a_dash
600 webm audio only      2 │   77.25KiB  33k https │ audio only         opus        33k 48k ultralow, webm_dash
139 m4a  audio only      2 │  114.69KiB  49k https │ audio only         mp4a.40.5   49k 22k low, m4a_dash
249 webm audio only      2 │  109.96KiB  47k https │ audio only         opus        47k 48k low, webm_dash
250 webm audio only      2 │  140.42KiB  60k https │ audio only         opus        60k 48k low, webm_dash
140 m4a  audio only      2 │  301.95KiB 130k https │ audio only         mp4a.40.2  130k 44k medium, m4a_dash
251 webm audio only      2 │  246.27KiB 106k https │ audio only         opus       106k 48k medium, webm_dash
394 mp4  192x144     15    │  133.31KiB  58k https │ av01.0.00M.08  58k video only          144p, mp4_dash
269 mp4  192x144     15    │ ~330.90KiB 139k m3u8  │ avc1.4D400B   139k video only
597 mp4  192x144     15    │   55.85KiB  24k https │ avc1.4d400b    24k video only          144p, mp4_dash
160 mp4  192x144     15    │  190.56KiB  82k https │ avc1.4D400B    82k video only          144p, mp4_dash
602 mp4  192x144     15    │ ~178.20KiB  75k m3u8  │ vp09.00.10.08  75k video only
603 mp4  192x144     15    │ ~327.55KiB 138k m3u8  │ vp09.00.11.08 138k video only
598 webm 192x144     15    │   49.19KiB  21k https │ vp9            21k video only          144p, webm_dash
278 webm 192x144     15    │  180.95KiB  78k https │ vp09.00.11.08  78k video only          144p, webm_dash
395 mp4  320x240     15    │  252.41KiB 109k https │ av01.0.00M.08 109k video only          240p, mp4_dash
229 mp4  320x240     15    │ ~581.41KiB 245k m3u8  │ avc1.4D400C   245k video only
133 mp4  320x240     15    │  422.66KiB 183k https │ avc1.4D400C   183k video only          240p, mp4_dash
18  mp4  320x240     15  1 │  772.82KiB 332k https │ avc1.42001E        mp4a.40.2       44k 240p
604 mp4  320x240     15    │ ~471.45KiB 199k m3u8  │ vp09.00.20.08 199k video only
242 webm 320x240     15    │  286.21KiB 124k https │ vp09.00.20.08 124k video only          240p, webm_dash
```

To download the desired variant, simply pass the desired format code (ID field, first column) with `-f` option, and that particular audio/video stream will be downloaded and saved. For e.g., execute the following command-line to download the audio component:

`yt-dlp -f 140 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw`

There are many more advanced options like looking up available subtitle files and downloading a specific one. The aforementioned options should suffice for casual usage.

**P.S.**: [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) supports downloading from over a 1000 popular streaming websites like Vimeo, Dailymotion etc. apart from YouTube.

Comment: Check my answer.  Using your answer I added a php script to download the videos. Thanks for the idea!!

Answer (score 4):

I use [Wondershare Video Converter](https://videoconverter.wondershare.com) to extract videos from Youtube, Vimeo, etc. Just paste in the URL of the video into the interface and it will extract and convert the video into many different available formats for all types of devices. It has never failed to work for me.

*Disclaimer: I'm a satisfied user of Wondershare Video Converter. No financial or other connection to the developer or owner of Wondershare*.

If you like command line tools - the [youtube-dl tool is amazing](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/). It can download, convert, process and slice and dice all manner of video and audio content that's hosted on the web.

```
$ brew info youtube-dl
youtube-dl: stable 2018.03.26.1, HEAD
Download YouTube videos from the command-line
https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/
/usr/local/Cellar/youtube-dl/2018.03.26.1 (12 files, 2.0MB) *
   Built from source on 2018-03-30 at 19:07:56
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/youtube-dl.rb
```

Comment: Mind if I edit in the home brew command line tool youtube-dl in to this as an option? I can make a stand alone answer, too.

Comment: Have at it, @bmike!

Comment: Done - looks like Nimesh beat us to the edit.

Comment: @Nimesh Neema is a diligent dude!

Comment: @bmike, IconDaemon: I am noticing this conversation only now :). Didn't intend to beat anyone, just wanted to write a good answer.

Comment: I shouldn’t say beat. It’s always great to have several people contributing good answers or in this case, great answers.

Answer (score 2):

https://telecharger-videos-youtube.com/en

Great website. Never had a problem with downloading videos. It does take a bit longer than most sites, but its worth the wait. You can select from many different qualities (1080p, 720p, etc.) and file type (mp4, mp3, etc).

**Note: As usual for sites like this there are some "questionable" advertisements. Some that are inappropriate. And some that are PopUps of fake software. I would suggest to get an ad-blocker. Use at your own risk.**

P.S. There are many different options just do a Google search of "Youtube to mp4" or "Youtube to mp3". MP4 is a video file format and MP3 is a audio-only file format.

As promised I have created a PHP script to download Youtube Videos with `youtube-dl`.

**Note: You must have `ffmpeg` and `youtube-dl` installed**

**Update: 9/13/19** This is coincidentally exactly one year since my last update. I have since archived the project. I do not suggested using it. Instead use something like [Node.js YouTube-dl](https://github.com/przemyslawpluta/node-youtube-dl) or [this PHP wrapper](https://github.com/norkunas/youtube-dl-php).

Heres the link: https://github.com/jbis9051/YouTubeDLWeb

Comment: Thanks for the caution about tracking / advertising / malware and just pushy ads.

Answer (score 2):

`youtube-dl` is great but if you want a GUI way to download video from YouTube and almost anywhere else, I highly recommend [Downie](https://software.charliemonroe.net/downie/).

It works great, it's constantly being improved, it's developed by a named, reputable developer (unlike some tools out there which seem a little "fly-by-night"), and it has some nice Mac-specific features.

There is a free trial available, and it's  also part of [Setapp](https://setapp.com/).

Answer (score -2):

If you use Firefox to browse YouTube, you will find that it has a plethora of add-on's that will allow you watch their videos without annoying ads, and even one-click to download buttons to quicken the video grabbing process.

Since Firefox is a browser aimed at security and privacy protection, you have less to worry about installing third party software and any potential monkey business kind of threats.

Add-ons are easily installed, disabled and removed and generally consumes fewer resources and leaves a lesser footprint on your operating system. Some allow specific folders for the video files to be saved in and allows to begin download immediately without dialogue boxes further quickening the grabbing process, while some allow downloading only the audio track as mp3 files.

Since the best one changes from time to time and differs from person to person, I will not list specific add-on names here. Hope that helps.