# Is it safe to install youtube-dl on my Mac?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, youtube

I recently came to know about [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) to download YouTube videos. My Mac is the main computer I use. I want to ensure I don't download any malicious script or software.

Is youtube-dl totally safe to download and install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is totally safe to install youtube-dl for downloading YouTube videos. See [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/321677/279727) answer.

It is recommended to install it via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).